# Spartacus not loading translations from local JSON files when using SSR

Tags: server-side-rendering, spartacus-storefront

When loading translations from json files in the local assets folder,they can't be loaded by the Node server when using Server-side rendering.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add config for loading translations from local files to the

```
i18n: {
  backend: {
    loadPath: 'assets/translations/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
  },
  chunks: translationChunksConfig,
  fallbackLang: 'en'
},
```

2. Activate Server-side rendering using the [Spartacus documentation](https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/server-side-rendering-in-spartacus/)
3. Build an run the SSR application using
   `yarn build:ssr` and 
   `yarn serve:ssr`
4. Deactivate Javascript in the browser to see what is rendered on the server
5. The translations are not loaded by the Node application: [image: List item]

One possible workaround is to just compile the translation into the code using Typescript files. But is there a way to also get this to work with JSON?

Thank you,
Armin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the issue was addressed before in in https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/issues/6030, there has been a new bug observed: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/issues/6307. The latter is fixed, but not yet merged. I've just raised priority and hope we can deliver this soon in a patch release for 1.4.x.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it. I am using Spartacus version 1.4.0-rc.1 to test this, which already contains this fix. Is it best to raise an additional issue in Github for this problem?

Comment: I created a ticket: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/issues/6307

Comment: Thanks @armin, will have a look. I've seen the same release message on the 1.4.0-rc.3 which is confusing. Perhaps the release message was wrong. Might be worth a try. btw, 1.4 final was released this week, you might want to upgrade anyway.

Comment: I updated the libraries to 1.4.0, but the problem still persists.